# Adjusting input for sorting code in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

I am a beginner in JavaScript and am creating a static website with a table with dynamic sorting. I am using the DataTables plugin for jQuery.

The issue I have is that some of the cells are empty, or have a dash instead of a numeric value. Under DataTables' sorting method, these cells show at the top for ascending sorting. However, I would like these cells always to show up at the bottom (because they contain no useful information).

Here is a link to the site with the full source code: http://lerium.com/wip/index.html

As you can see in the source, I am trying to use the following script for columns 3 and 4:

```
function testNumericEmptyBottom(a, b, high) {
        var reg = /[+-]?((\d+(\.\d*)?)|\.\d+)([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?/;
        a = $(a).text().match(reg);
        a = a !== null && parseInt(a[0]) !== 0 ? parseInt(a[0]) : high;
        b = $(b).text().match(reg);
        b = b !== null && parseInt(b[0]) !== 0 ? parseInt(b[0]) : high;
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    }
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
        "numeric-empty-bottom-asc": function(a, b) {
            return testNumericEmptyBottom(a, b, Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
        },
        "numeric-empty-bottom-desc": function(a, b) {
            return testNumericEmptyBottom(a, b, Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) * -1;
        }
    });
```

However, because the numbers are not integers, this is not working. I have tried to change to floating-type for the parseInt, but that didn't work, and I also tried toLocaleString. I imagine that the problem is that i have percentages, and in my language we use commas instead of dots for the decimal denotation.

Can you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do, numeric value or not, is to have a custom sorting result.

This sorting implies you change values depending on the sorting direction (asc/desc) to have it sorted on the last rows.

My first idea was to use hidden columns having a number like "10000" if there is a dash in the previous column. That worked... But on `desc` order, again, the dashed whent back on top.

Every callbacks and event seems to occur after DataTables has sorted the rows. So I couldn't change the value to zero on descending order.
There is no "before sort" hook, sadly.

And all this was quite complicated for no big result.

So just when I was about to give up, I had the opposite idea. It doesn't work "before sort", then lets "fix" the sorting after. All that I needed was which row triggers the sorting.

I ended up using the [`drawCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) which, like many callbacks, provides the full Datatables object. I found the sorting direction and triggering column in that object.

Now what was left to do was to cycle through each rows to check the HTML contained in that column index... And append the whole row at the end of the table if a dash is found.

That works!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var datatable = $('#lan').DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "ordering": true,
    "info": false,
    "searching": false,
    "drawCallback" : renderFix
  });

  function renderFix(dataTableObj){

    var counter = 0;

    // Get the sorting direction and the column index which triggered
    var direction = dataTableObj.aaSorting[0][1];
    var triggerringCol = dataTableObj.aaSorting[0][0];
    console.log("Sorted column "+triggerringCol+", "+direction+"ending.");

    // If the trigger to sort occured on a column in this array
    var columnsToChange = [2,3,4,5];
    if(columnsToChange.indexOf(triggerringCol) != -1){

      // On each row in the "triggering column",
      // if the HTML is "-", append it to the end.
      // The result is a "move".
      $(".container tbody tr").each(function(){
        thisTD = $(this).find("td").eq(triggerringCol);

        if( thisTD.html() == "-" ){
          $('#lan').append( $(this) );
          counter++;
        }

      });
      console.log(counter+" row(s) moved down.")
    }
  } // renderFix

}); // Ready
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/jGbNbN?editors=0010)

Comment: Nicely explained solution! Since the original approach did not work, just try some other way.